# Paging Library - DataSource didn't invalidate itself after BoundaryCallback called

Tags: android, paging, android-room, android-architecture-components

In the given [PagingWithNetworkSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/PagingWithNetworkSample) ,:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE subreddit = :subreddit ORDER BY indexInResponse ASC")
fun postsBySubreddit(subreddit : String) : DataSource.Factory<Int, RedditPost>
```

Here they use `LimitOffsetDataSource<T> extends TiledDataSource<T>`  as provider,

it will invalidate when the specific tables have updated:

```
mObserver = new InvalidationTracker.Observer(tables) {
        @Override
        public void onInvalidated(@NonNull Set<String> tables) {
            invalidate();
        }
    };
db.getInvalidationTracker().addWeakObserver(mObserver);
```

But in my case:

```
class StatusDataSource() : PageKeyedDataSource<String, Status>() {

// additional code, not my expected
init {
    db.invalidationTracker.addObserver(object : InvalidationTracker.Observer("statuses") {
        override fun onInvalidated(tables: MutableSet<String>) {
            invalidate()
        }
    })
}

override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams<String>, callback: LoadInitialCallback<String, Status>) {
    val data = dao.loadInitial(path, params.requestedLoadSize)
    if (data.isEmpty()) {
        callback.onResult(data, null, null)
    } else {
        callback.onResult(data, null, data.last().id)
    }
}

// additional code, not my expected  
override fun isInvalid(): Boolean {
    db.invalidationTracker.refreshVersionsAsync()
    return super.isInvalid()
    }
}
```

I've created a class extends `PageKeyedDataSource`  ,but things do not turn out as expected: If there is run out of data in `room` , at first `load()` will return EMPTY, then the `BoudaryCallback` will be triggered to fetch data from server :

```
@MainThread
override fun onZeroItemsLoaded() {
    helper.runIfNotRunning(PagingRequestHelper.RequestType.INITIAL) {
        webservice.fetch_from_path(path = path, count = networkPageSize, id = uniqueId).enqueue(createWebserviceCallback(it))
    }
}
```

**BUT** after I've inserted items into `db`, the `StatusDataSource`  didn't invalidate itself.

Need I add the addtional code aboved, to obsever the "statuses" table and invalidate the data source?

But it seems NOT a efficient way…and what's worse, when the data loaded, `recyclerView` can't persist in   its scroll position (the bottom),but scroll to some position.Seemingly , this invalidation method can't work properly with `pagedList` (´ｰ ｀)ｷﾗｯ

If anyone give me a working example much appreciated, thx in advance (๑￣∀￣)